# How to switch from local api call to production api call with react native web with expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a react native web app with expo. And I call at the moment the api call from localhost. But I also have a remote server with of course a other url. How to change the api call for producion?

So I installed

> "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",

And I created two env files: dev and production:
.env

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false 
REACT_APP_NAME=dev
API_URL=http://127.0.0.1
```

env.prod

```
REACT_APP_ENV=PRODUCTION
API_URL=https://dierenwelzijndocker.azurewebsites.net
```

And I changed the babel.config.js file:

```
/* eslint-disable comma-dangle */
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
        plugins: [
            "babel-plugin-styled-components-react-native-web",
            [
                "module:react-native-dotenv",
                {
                    envName: "APP_ENV",
                    moduleName: "@env",
                    path: ".env",
                    blocklist: null,
                    allowlist: null,
                    safe: false,
                    allowUndefined: false,
                    verbose: false,
                },
            ],
        ],
    };
};
```

and this is the api call:

```
import { API_URL } from "@env";
export const loginRequest = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/user/token/`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password,
            }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();

        if (response.ok) {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("Token", data.token);
            //
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new Error(data.token);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        error, "email en of wachtwoord is niet goed ingevuld";
    }
};
```

and so this works for local development.

But if I to production. I build a web-build folder with the command > `npx expo export:web`

And I have my package.json like:

```
"start:production": "NODE_ENV=production npx expo export:web .env.production --openssl-legacy-provider, react-app-rewired start react-scripts start",
        "start:development": "NODE_ENV=development expo start --openssl-legacy-provider, react-app-rewired start react-scripts start",
```

and a folder web-build has been created in the root folder. but the api calls are still for localhost.

Question: how to change the api call from local to production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv#multi-env) you can overwrite the environment used with your package.json command

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start:development": "NODE_ENV=development {your command}",
    "start:production": "NODE_ENV=production {your command}",
  }
}
```

Comment: I create the production folder with this command:  npx expo export:web. So my package.json have to look like "start:production": "NODE_ENV=production npx expo export:web .env.production --openssl-legacy-provider, react-app-rewired start react-scripts start",
  "start:development": "NODE_ENV=development expo start --openssl-legacy-provider, react-app-rewired start react-scripts start",

Comment: @Xiduzo.see my comment. Is this the correct way?

Comment: you should have a `.env` file for local development and `.env.production` and your commands should be `"export:local": "NODE_ENV=development npx expo export:web"` for local use and `"export:production": "NODE_ENV=production npx expo export:web"` to use the `.env.production` file

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Environment Variables:

- Define different environment variables for your API endpoints. For
  example,
  you might have a DEV_API_URL for local development and a PROD_API_URL for
  production.

2. Create Configuration Files:

- Create configuration files (config.js or similar) where you define these
  environment variables based on the environment.

3. Import Configuration Based on Environment:

- Import the appropriate configuration file based on the environment
  (development or production). You might switch between these
  configurations during build time or dynamically based on the runtime environment.

config.js:

```
let apiUrl;
if (_DEV_) {
  apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'; // Your local API URL
} else {
  apiUrl = 'https://production-api.com'; // Your production API URL
}

export { apiUrl };

import { apiUrl } from './config';
// Use apiUrl in your fetch requests
fetch(`${apiUrl}/endpoint`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    // Handle data
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle errors
  });
```